# Why is the property overflow with the value absolute positioning the tooltip there?

Tags: css

I saw this  "TryIy" link:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip

But I didnt understan...
I know the porpose of `position:absolute;`, but why isnt it displayed on the text, or at the left? why does the tooltip appear at the right bottom corner of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is located in a div with a set width and height. The parent div position is relative and so the absolute div will not go out of the relative div.

Comment: yhea yhea... but why at the left bottom corner?

Comment: @efwef because thats how it stacks.

Comment: "Thats how" isnt an answer for people who love the programming just because...But thanks any way man!